# I want to add three Text boxes with three different conditons

Tags: c#

[image]

I have added three text boxes and one datetimePiker,

when I select any value from DateTimePiker it will show to the Textbox1

if the value is <18 it will show a message and then add 30 to it and then add to the Textbox2

or if value is >50 then it will also show message and add 30 in it ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. The question is not very clear. But I think you can use nested if to solve this problem.

```
if(%conditions%){ //logic }
else if(%condition number 2%) { //logic } 
.
.
.
else { //logic }
```

[Examples of nested if](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/nested_if_statements_in_csharp.htm)